# Training a Logistic Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to train a logistic classifier. My dataset has the following columns.

**name**    ,   **review**, **rating**, **reviews_cleaned** , **word_count**,    **sentiment**,

The sentiment is either +1 or -1 based on whether the rating is greater than 3 or less. The word count contains a dict of words with occurences and reviews_cleaned just strips off the reviews off punctuations.

This is my code to train a `LogisticClassifier`.

```
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(products, test_size = 0.2)
sentiment_model = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1)
sentiment_model.fit(products['sentiment'], products['word_count'])
```

I get the following error,

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 166752]
```

PS: The equivalent statment using `graphLab` create is

```
sentiment_model = graphlab.logistic_classifier.create(train_data,
                                                      target = 'sentiment',
                                                      features=['word_count'],
                                                      validation_set=None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `sentiment_model.fit(products[['word_count']], products['sentiment'])`

Comment: This returns `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'`

Comment: I hadn't realized that your target and features were switched. In the `fit` method, the input is `fit(X, y, ...)`, where `X` is an array, and `y` a vector.

Comment: Remember that you are not using the `train_test_split` in this case. Don't forget to use this later.

Comment: @ssm I'm just learning machine learning, so I'm a little unclear. So how do I convert my dict into an array and a column to a vector?

Comment: Those things are `dicts`? I thought you were using Pandas DataFrames. If you are unfamiliar with them, I suggest you learn them first before going into ML. It will save you a *lot* of time ... See here: http://pandas.pydata.org

Comment: The data is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @ssm retrying your first comment now gives. `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'`

Comment: Further to ssm's comments. If you subset using a single bracket. e.g. df[colname] it returns a pandas Series object. Whereas, if you subset using a double bracket, e.g. df[[colname]] it will return a dataframe. The Series is 1-dimensional whereas the dataframe is 2-dimensional. Assuming your data (i.e. products) is in fact a pandas.DataFrame.

Comment: @Oq01 I'm still getting an error which I can't seem to resolve, thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: What does type(products) return?

Comment: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Comment: I think your datatypes within one of your columns are not float objects. They are dicts. This is what is causing problems.

Comment: @Oq01 yes the `train_data['word_count']` contains `dicts` , of words against the number to times they occur in a review, which is what I want to use to assign coefficients to each word for my sentiment classifier. Please see the equivalent statement in graphlab.

Comment: I am not too familiar with graphlab. But look at this example for clarity on how sklearn would expect the data. 

`df = pd.DataFrame({'word_count': [3,3,3], 'sentiment': [-1, 1, 1]})`


`clf.fit(df[['word_count']], df['sentiment'])`

Comment: Well that's not the form my data is in, my `train_data['word_count']` example is `{'it': 3, 'came': 1, 'early': 1, 'and': 3}`. Is there a way I can train the classifier on this?

Comment: Not in that form no. You will have to transform the data. If you want to use each word as a feature to the model, you need to create a column for each of those words and the values will be the corresponding word-counts. See sklearn's CountVectorizer. It produces such a 2d matrix from raw text and uses a sparse matrix object, which will ensure it doesn't consume too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your training data looks like it's a 1-dimensional vector but sklearn requires it to be 2-dimensional - if you `reshape` it you should be okay. Also you make your train/test split but you're not actually using the data that you're producing (fit with train_data instead).

Comment: I've suitably amended to use the train_data, but could you write the equivalent code for what I'm reshaping. Sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Using GraphLab in that course is *very* irritating to say the least. Give this a whirl:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv('amazon_baby.csv', header = 0)

df.dropna(how="any", inplace= True)

products = df[df['rating'] != 3] #drop the products with 3-star rating
products['sentiment'] = products['rating'] >= 4

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(products['review'], products['sentiment'], test_size = .2 ,random_state = 0)

vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vect.fit_transform(X_train.values)
X_test = vect.transform(X_test.values)

model = LogisticRegression(penalty ='l2', C = 1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm not sure what the direct translation between Sklearn/Pandas and GraphLab is, but this looks like it's what they are doing.

When I score the model, I get:

```
model.score(X_test, y_test)
> .93155480
```

Let me know what results you get or if this works for you.